# Python - export fields to a CSV

Tags: python, csv

```
for i in tweets_df.ix[:,0]:
    if regex_getter(i) != None:
        city,state = regex_getter(i).split(',')
        print(city,state)
```

I am essentially just trying to write city and state to csv. Print city and state prints exactly what i have below minus the headers

my csv should look like

```
City State
Burlington  VT
Minneapolis  MN
Bloomington  IN
Irvine  CA
```

Comment: You can open files for reading/writing using `open(filename,'a')` (the `a` means "append", so you can write line-by-line.) Is this what you're looking for? There's also a csv module which could be handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `csv` module to do this:

`writerow` will take an iterable and write each item in the iterable in a separate column.

```
import csv
....
with open("test.csv", "w", newline='') as csvfile:
     writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
     #write header, or something
     for i in tweets_df.ix[:,0]:
          if regex_getter(i) != None:
              data = regex_getter(i).split(',')
              writer.writerow(data)
```

Comment: AttributeError: module 'csv' has no attribute 'writerow' this is what i ran into

Comment: See the edit, I made a mistake don't know what I was thinking as I typed `csv.writerow`. You have to use `writer` to write :)

Comment: Just write it to the `csv` with the `writer`. Easiest way here is probably (after writer) `writer.writerow(['City', 'State'])`. So, just replace the comment with that line.

Comment: Thank you exactly what i needed! :)